# Удаление лишних полей из json при помощи regex в Notepad++

Tags: json, notepad++

Есть огромный json-файл с данными весом в 9 мегабайт. С целью уменьшения размера файла и ускорения загрузки скрипта было принято решение удалить неиспользуемые поля:

```
{
 "airports": [
  {
   "fs": "BBA",
   "iata": "BBA",
   "icao": "SCBA",
   "name": "Teniente Vidal Airport",
   "city": "Balmaceda",
   "cityCode": "BBA",
   "countryCode": "CL",
   "countryName": "Chile",
   "regionName": "South America",
   "timeZoneRegionName": "America/Santiago",
   "localTime": "2017-01-22T06:56:21.606",
   "utcOffsetHours": -3,
   "latitude": -45.916667,
   "longitude": -71.695,
   "elevationFeet": 1722,
   "classification": 4,
   "active": true,
   "weatherUrl": "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/weather/rest/v1/json/all/BBA?codeType=fs",
   "delayIndexUrl": "https://api.flightstats.com/flex/delayindex/rest/v1/json/airports/BBA?codeType=fs"
  }]}
```

Таких массивов данных около 16.000. Хочу убрать из всех массивов данных поля fs, icao, cityCode, countryCode, regionName, localTime, active, weatherUrl и delayIndexUrl. Редакторов json-массива я не нашёл, по этому единственной возможностью вижу удаление этих полей при помощи регулярных выражений в Notepad++. Помогите, пожалуйста, составить регулярные выражения для удаления этих полей. Или, если знаете онлайн-ресурс, где можно редактировать json - подскажите. Премного благодарен.

Comment: я думаю нужно не регулярное выражение, а написать скрипт на каком-то знакомом языке программирования, я бы на java писал или perl

Comment: есть чудная штука - [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/), которая как раз и поможет решить заданный вопрос.

Comment: проще реально открыть ЯП, загрузить json, удалить поля и сохранить. Работы по написанию кода минуты три

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл простой и элегантный способ удалять ненужные поля в json при помощи регулярного выражения:

```
\r\s*"localTime":\s".*",
```

`r\s*` — удаление пробелов и переноса строк, чтобы не создавать пустые строки

`"localTime":\s` — название поля и пробел после него

`".*",` — значение поля. Независимо от количества и типа символов будет удалено всё, что заключено в кавычки и запятая в конце.